# Promotion Conditions Combination possible?

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, promotions

I'm pretty new in the world of SE and indeed Magento so please do let me know if I need to re-format my question or add more information.

I'm trying to create a promotion where if a customer adds multiples of 3 different products to the cart and applies a specific coupon code, they get a set amount discount per set of 3 products.

For example:-

- Customer added 1 x product1, 1 x product2 and 1 x product3 to the
  cart they would receive a discount of £6 after entering the code.
- Customer added 2 x product1, 2 x product2 and 2 x product3 to the
  cart they would receive a discount of £12 after entering the code.
- Customer added 2 x product1, 2 x product2 and 1 x product3 to the
  cart they would receive £6 discount after entering the code.

Each set of 3 must consist of one of each product.

So my question is, is it possible to implement this rule within the Shopping Cart Price Rules in Magento Admin or does it need to be applied programmatically?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with creating 3 separate "Shopping Cart Rules" for each discount.

What you need to do is the following:

**1. Allow "SKU's" to be used for Promo rules**

You need to go to Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes and edit the "sku" attribute. You need to set "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" to "Yes" and click save. This will allow the sku attribute to be used for creating "Shopping Cart Rules".

**2. Create 3 Shopping Cart Rules**

If you go to Promotions -> Shopping Cart Rules you will need to create 3 rules for each discount.

So when creating the rule you need to use the following setting (replace sku's, quantity and discount for each rule)

1. Rule Information

Name: Discount 1
Description: Discount 1
Status: Active
Customer Groups: (select groups this rule should applied to)
Coupon: Specific Coupon
Coupon Code: test (replace with your own coupon code)
Priority: 0
Public In RSS Feed: No (assuming you don't want the coupon found via RSS feed)

2. Conditions

This is tricky but for each product you need to hit the plus sign and select "Product attribute combination".

Then you need to click the plus sign underneath the text "If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true:" and select "SKU" and set the product sku value. You then need to click the plus sign again and select "Quantity in cart" and set the value to either 1,2 or 3 for each cart rule.

3. Actions

Apply: "Fixed amount for discount for whole cart"
Discount Amount: 6 or 12 depending on the rule
Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To: 0
Discount Qty Step (Buy X): 0
Apply to Shipping Amount: No
Free Shipping: No
Stop Further Rules Processing: Yes (stops other coupons been applied based off the priority)

You should then save the rule and it should work once you have added the right quantities to the cart and enter in the coupon code. I have tested this on a vanilla install of RWD.